# Objective - C, protocols, arrays, dictionary - test

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, dictionary, protocols

That may not be a proper place to ask such questions but I'll try.
I have a test from Objective - C tomorrow and I wanted to make sure if I know answers to questions.

### 1. How to define array with three strings?

```
NSArray *a = @[@"String1", @"String2", @"String3"];
```

### 2. How to define dictionary with three pairs string-int?

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = @{
     @"String1" : [NSNumber numberWithInt:1],
     @"String2" : [NSNumber numberWithInt:2],
     @"String3" : [NSNumber numberWithInt:3],
};
```

### 3. Create protocol containing three methods - first and last must be optional.

```
@protocol myProtocol
@optional
-(void)someMethod1:(id)someArgument;
@required
-(void)someMethod2:(id)someArgument;
@optional
-(void)someMethod3:(id)someArgument;
@end
```

### 4. Protocol ABC looks like this:

```
@protocol 
  -(int) def: (NSString *)a;
@end
```

Call method def from this protocol for a variable:

```
id <ABC> c;

[self.c def:self];
```

### 5. Create variable of type NSString in three different ways

```
NSString *s = [ NSString stringWithFormat:@”String”];
NSString *s = [[ NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@”String"];
NSString *s =@”String”;
```

### 6. Alocated and initialised NSArray. Can we add any new object to this array? Why?

No cause this array is only filled during initialisation.

### 7. Alocated and initialised NSMutableSet. Can we add any new object to this collection? Why?

Yes cause NSMutableSet has method to add objects.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its a series of questions about various concepts / fundamentals of obj-c or swift. OP is just too lazy to google up references and learn.

Comment: 4.: I'd make an use of return value: `int returnValue = [self.c def:self];`. Showing that you understood that there is a return, may be unused, but still, you can use this value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**2. How to define dictionary with three pairs string-int?**
Use the literal syntax for `NSNumbers`.

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = @{
     @"String1" : @1,
     @"String2" : @2,
     @"String3" : @3
};
```

**5. Create variable of type NSString in three different ways**
Use `withString` instead of `withFormat` when there is no format:

```
NSString *s = [NSString stringWithstring:@”String”];
NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@”String"];
```

**6. Alocated and initialised NSArray. Can we add any new object to this array? Why?**
No because it is immutable.

**7. Alocated and initialised NSMutableSet. Can we add any new object to this collection? Why?**
Yes because it is mutable.

Note re 6 & 7: Mutable: *liable to change*, the value can be changed. Immutable: *unchanging over time or unable to be changed*, the value can not be changed.

Comment: I'd had to question 7. that NSMutableSet is mutable, relating it to question 6.

Comment: You "corrected" author's answer for question 6 talking about immutable. So I'd suggest that you correct also his answer about question 7, opposing mutable/immutable, because "Yes cause NSMutableSet has method to add objects." seems a poor answer.

Comment: @Larme Added question 7.